# how secure credentials in an ajax request to get a token (oauth)

Tags: ajax, security, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I'm building a SPA application that uses my API through the OAuth Authentication mechanism. My application doesn't has a login view, so I get a token by writing the username and password in the code same, in this way:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:  restServer + "/token",
  dataType: 'json',
  // insecure :
  data: {
     grant_type   : 'password',
     scope        : '*',
     username     : 'someuser',
     password     : 'p4sSw0rd'         
  }
})
//...
```

but obviously it is an insecure way to do this, everyone can read the username and the password.
I tried to find about this problem on stackoverflow, etc. but I don't understand how I can solve it.

someone says to get the user and password from the server, but it has the same security problem.
someone mentions https, but in this first step it is not involved.

someone has ideas?

Comment: I think the common solution would be hashing the password, because it might be transferred in plain-text anyway if you don't use an TLS connection.
Also you might move this question to http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

You should not keep usernames and passwords around in your JavaScript code. They are too easy to be stolen.

SPA application are supposed to use the [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) in OAuth 2.0. That means on log in you redirect the client to the authorization server to authenticate. The authorization server will redirect the client back to your SPA after authentication and authorization completed. The resulting access token (JWT token) can be used to make calls to your REST API in the backend.

When the access token expires, you communicate with the authorization server to get a new token. User interaction may be required for this.

Comment: But how I said I don't have a login view, so how I can get the token securing the credentials ?

Comment: It's not your application that shows the login view, but the authorization server. Which returns the token on successful authentication.

Comment: But I don't want that the users need to login in a login view, I want that it is automatic, and without user interactions. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Then you should look at Kerberos authentication. But that will only work inside your domain. OAuth supports a password grant, but you cannot do this securely from a JavaScript client.